# Turning Issue With Vex Robot C++

Tags: c++, robotics

When we use the joystick with axises 1 and 2 to turn, when we turn left the robot turns right and when we turn right the robot turns left. We've tried switching different values to make some negative to reverse this but nothing seems to work. We've also tried making the left motor reversed instead of the right motor and it corrected the problem but the forward and backward are switched.

```
  while (true) { 
      int rightSpeed= (Controller1.Axis3.position(vex::pct) + 
                              (Controller1.Axis1.position(vex::pct) + Controller1.Axis4.position(vex::pct)));

      int leftSpeed= (Controller1.Axis1.position(vex::pct) - 
                              (Controller1.Axis2.position(vex::pct) + Controller1.Axis3.position(vex::pct)));

      if (leftSpeed>15||leftSpeed<-15){
          RightMotor.spin(vex::directionType::fwd, leftSpeed, vex::velocityUnits::pct);   
      }

      if (rightSpeed>15||rightSpeed<-15){
           LeftMotor.spin(vex::directionType::fwd, rightSpeed, vex::velocityUnits::pct);
           RightMotor.spin(vex::directionType::fwd, -leftSpeed, vex::velocityUnits::pct);    
      }  
  }
```

Comment: I notice that you're calling RightMotor.spin(..., *leftSpeed*,...). Is that intentional? Also, it looks like both the motors are directed to spin if rightSpeed's absolute value is greater than 15. Is this line a mistake? `RightMotor.spin(vex::directionType::fwd, -leftSpeed, vex::velocityUnits::pct);`

Comment: The best option to get a good result would be to go to the vex forums (vexforums.com) and there is a wider range of people there who know the answers to the questions